# Flutter NFC reader plugin does not work with error inside plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc

I'm trying to make a flutter version of my old app , it needs NFC .

First I create a default project for test run and it works fine.

I tried to use [flutter-nfc-reader](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader) and install it following "Installation" in that default project.

And here comes the problem:

After I edit "pubspec.yaml" and do "packeges get" , it automatically edit "GeneratedPluginRegistrant" under "myapp/android/app/src/main/java/io.flutter.plugins".

added

```
import it.matteocrippa.flutternfcreader.FlutterNfcReaderPlugin;
```

and

```
FlutterNfcReaderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("it.matteocrippa.flutternfcreader.FlutterNfcReaderPlugin"));
```

But the import can't find that package "it.matteocrippa.flutternfcreader" which is inside the plugin.

I tried just copy that package but that file will be full of error when it is inside my project.

I have no idea how to fix it....

Comment: which NFC chip you were using and in which platform ? i see the tag type supported differently in iOS/Android like (MiFare , FeliCa - iOS) and  (NfcA
NfcB - Android)

Answer (score 0):

As [Github](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader) reads:

> last step import to the project:
>
> `import 'package:flutter_nfc_reader/flutter_nfc_reader.dart';`

Comment: Where to import?  I did tried to import it in main.dart and GeneratedPluginRegistrant  but no effect.....

Comment: I still can't find where to add that import , please help

Comment: @范植勝 this goes into `lib/main.dart`, on top. see the [example](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader/tree/master/example). That Flutter plugin seems to be discontinued, the author is looking for a new maintainer.

Comment: Still not working but thank you. I'll try to find another plugin.